# Does melatonin supplementation affect depression?

Tags: mental-health, depression, supplement, melatonin

Is there any evidence that melatonin supplementation contributes to, or reduces, depression?

I have asked two experts about this, and got two different answers.  One said that melatonin supplementation can contribute to depression, and the other said he had never heard of melatonin contributing to depression.

Comment: melatonin has been linked to some help with sleep.  Lack of good sleep and definitely insomnia has been linked to depression.  Plausible as I think you had stated.